# Session variable lost after redirect for feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, capybara-webkit

The session object is cleared after redirect during testing.

First, my test stack. I am running a Rails 4.2.4 app with capybara 2.6.2, capybara-webkit 1.8.0, and rspec 3.3.0. My tests were running without issue until, for no apparent reason whatsoever, they weren't.

Below is my code (condensed to stay on point):

**assessment_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @assessment_basic = Assessment::Basic.new(params)
  if @assessment_basic.valid?
    session[:most_recent_zip_code] = @assessment_basic.zip_code
    if household.search.present?
      update_household_search(@assessment_basic.zip_code)
    end

    redirect_to dashboard_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

def household
  if @household
    @household
  elsif session[:household_id]
    @household = find_household(session[:household_id])
  elsif session[:most_recent_zip_code]
    @household = Household.create(household_params)
    session[:household_id] = @household.id
  end
  @household
end
```

As you can see, this is pretty straight-forward. I am receiving a zip code in the params. I store that zip code for later use and use it to create a household object unless one already exists, in which case I return that instance. If a household object is instantiated, I then store its id in the session, return control back to the action and redirect to the dashboard_path having two variables in session. All of this works well, and has worked well for some time now.

However, when I try to access the variables in the dashboard#index action, none of the session variables I stored are present. The feature works, which suggests that my problem is with the bits running my specs. By the way, the spec passes locally. It is when the code is moved to our CI environment that we get the error. We tried three different CI environments (Circle, Semaphore, and Travis) and they all report the same error:

`#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'search' for nil:NilClass>`

Which basically means, the household could not be recreated and is therefore nil. A closer look shows the reason the household could not be created from session is that the session was cleared.

Can someone help me identify the component(s) involved in ensuring session values persists during tests? Let me know if you need anything else in order to be able to help me.

Hector

```
  it 'a client visits the referrals page with all providers minus the single stop and tax locations from the dashboard page and ' do
    user_visits_the_homepage

    enter_zip_code('11217', true)

    dashboard_page.expect_to_be_on
    dashboard_page.click_browse_local_resources

    referrals_page.expect_to_be_on
  end

  def user_visits_the_homepage
    visit '/'
    expect(page).to have_content t('welcome.where')
  end

  def enter_zip_code(zip_code = '11217', remain_dashboard = false)
    within '.welcome-form:nth-of-type(1)' do
      fill_in t('welcome.where'), with: zip_code
      click_on t('welcome.get_started')
    end

    expect(page).to have_content t('header.dashboard')
    click_on t('header.your_profile') unless remain_dashboard

    expect(page).to have_field t('activerecord.attributes.client_household_member.zip_code'), with: zip_code unless remain_dashboard
  end
```

Comment: Are you building capybara-webkit with the same version of Qt locally as you are on the CI environments?

Comment: It could be that the CI servers are faster than your local env. The test has finished, and starts cleaning session & db, but the request to the index route only just fired. The action errors during the post test cleaning, and bubbles up to make the test fail even though it was already done. Could you add the code for the failing test?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I think you may have a point on the QT versions. My CI uses qt5-default on a Ubuntu 14.04 box. I am not sure but I think that defaults to QT 5.2.1. I am running QT 5.5.1 on my development machine. I am trying to figure out how to install qtchooser to select a QT version to run the code on. I am not very experienced on this, so thank you for the reply and your suggestion.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech, thanks for replying. Below is the feature spec failing. I added the failing spec to my original question.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, I am having difficulty figuring out how to install the version of QT I am running on my development machine. I am running this command `sudo apt-get install netbase libqt5webkit5-dev qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev; true` but it doesn't seem to do the trick. I also tried `sudo apt-get install netbase libqt5webkit5-dev qt-latest libqt5webkit5-dev; true`, but it's not working. As far as capybara and capybara-webkit is concerned, I am running 2.13.0 and 1.14.0 respectively. Do you see any errors with any of these instructions and gems that will cause this issue?

Comment: @HectorSanchez  Sorry, I'm not really sure what you need to install to get the same qt version installed, however  you should probably try running the master branch of capybara-webkit and the latest capybara since there have been a number of updates and fixes since the last capybara-webkit release.

Comment: @HectorSanchez One other to look at since your issue is session based (cookies), are the domains being visited/redirected to the same?

Comment: @ThomasWalpoleThey are the same. I just realized I failed to specify in my original question that my failing specs had all been passing until about two weeks ago. I don't believe I changed anything that will make my specs fail.